# Is it possible to get Object ID in the OAuth Token from ADFS

Tags: oauth, adfs

Best reference for my question is [Getting the user profiles from ADFS3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27417487/getting-the-user-profiles-from-adfs3-0#) which shows the token ADFS OAuth is returning. My problem is that there is no GUID in this token. UPS are always emails, which can be assigned and changed. I need a GUID that would uniquely identify one user for now and later. If I search LDAP there is a GUID for a user entry. So my question is : is it possible to get that GUID in the OAuth token?

Thanks,
-Jayant.

Answer (score 0):

There are different end points in Identity server. One of the end point is `UserInfoEndpoint` which actually contains user information. And also it is not safe to get the user information in the `Access Token` by itself as the user information can be leaked if the token is used by someone else.

You can use the access token to query the userinfoEndpoint and get the user details. Also you can ask for permissions to access this information and when needed you can use the access token to get the `GUID`.

Is the `GUID` is the `SubjectId` that is unique for the user? Cause I think in any Identity server they have `SubjectID` unique to user.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand the concern on security. Object id seems like essential part of the token. Actually Azure OAuth token has the OID in the token. Should have mentioned that. That's why I thought there must be some way in adfs too and I am missing some configuration. I tried setting up custom claim rules, but the token content never changes.

Comment: Also I don't see a userinfo endpoint in my adfs endpoints list. I am running windows server 2012 R2.